# How can I visualize timeseries data aggregated by more than one dimension on AWS insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'd like to use cloudwatch insights to visualize a multiline graph of average latency by host over time. One line for each host.

This stats query extracts the latency and aggregates it in 10 minute buckets by host, but it doesn't generate any visualization.

```
stats avg(latencyMS) by bin(10m), host

bin(10m) | host | avg(latencyMS)
0m       |    1 |           120
0m       |    2 |           220
10m      |    1 |           130
10m      |    2 |           230
```

The docs call this out as a common mistake but don't offer any alternative.

> The following query does not generate a visualization, because it contains more than one grouping field.
>
> ```
> stats avg(myfield1) by bin(5m), myfield4
> ```
>
> [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_Insights-Visualizing-TimeSeries.html)

Experementally, cloudwatch will generate a multi line graph if each record has multiple keys. A query that would generate a line graph must return results like this:

```
bin(10m) | host-1 avg(latencyMS) | host-2 avg(latencyMS)
0m       |    120                |                   220
10m      |    130                |                   230
```

I don't know how to write a query that would output that.

Answer (score 12):

Parse individual message for each host then compute their stats.

For example, to get average latency for responses from processes with **PID=11** and **PID=13**.

```
parse @message /\[PID:11\].* duration=(?<pid_11_latency>\S+)/
| parse @message /\[PID:13\].* duration=(?<pid_13_latency>\S+)/
| display @timestamp, pid_11_latency, pid_13_latency
| stats avg(pid_11_latency), avg(pid_13_latency) by bin(10m)
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

The regular expressions extracts duration for processes having id `11` and `13` to parameters `pid_11_latency` and `pid_13_latency` respectively and fills `null` where there is no match series-wise.

You can build from this example by creating the match regular expression that extracts for metrics from message for hosts you care about.

Comment: Thanks, I did eventually figure this out and your answer is spot-on for my use case where I was happy to hard-code the hosts in the query.

Comment: How to make PID dynamic? For example, hosts can grow over the time, so each time I can have more, or even imagine that you have a hundred of them. Place a hundred parse lines is not efficient

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to handle this dynamically? I have a use case where I don't know how many "hosts" I'll have in the data set or what their values will be, but I would like to see the different values over time what ever the are.

Comment: I ended up exporting data to excel and creating a PivotChart